# Dropzone - dynamically append dropzone div not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, append, dropzone.js

Dropzone that dynamically appending by jquery not working.

The method i use for all of the dropzone is working, but need to click twice then only can work, at the same time google chrome return me an error.

Code of append dropzone:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
   $('.target').append("<div class='dropzone sales_proof_pic' data-proof-user-id='0'><div class='dz-message dropzone_placeholder color_khaki2' data-dz-message><span>UPLOAD<br>SALES<br>PROOF</span></div></div><input type='hidden' name='proof_id[0]' class='proof_pic_id'>");
});
```

Code of method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sales_proof_pic', function() {
   var proof_pic = $(this);
   $(this).dropzone({
      url: 'url',
      acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
      maxFiles: 1,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
         formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
         formData.append("usage", "NOTICE");
      },
      init: function(){
         this.on("success", function(file, response) {
            file.previewElement.id = response;
            proof_pic.siblings('.proof_pic_id').val(response);
         });

         this.on("removedfile",function(file){
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ?
 _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
         });
      },
      removedfile: function(file) {
         var id = file.previewElement.id;
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/admin/assets/delete/'+id,
            success: function(response){
              proof_pic.siblings('.proof_pic_id').val("");
            }
         });
       }
   });
});
```

Error return by browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.
    at new c (dropzone.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (dropzone.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:384)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.js:136)
    at m.fn.init.undefined.jQuery.fn.dropzone (dropzone.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (create:355)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
```

Is there any way to solve the problem? i the `var proof_pic = $(this);` cannot be remove, because i need this to record the value in an input

Comment: you add a new element with css class dropzone on each click. That could work for first click, but as soon as you click a second time, element added in first click with already dropzone attached will give you this error message

Answer (score 1):

At

```
$(this).dropzone({
```

you are creating a new dropzone area. Change that line to

```
Dropzone.options.myDropZone = {
```

and assign "*myDropZone*" as the id for the append div as follows:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
   $('.target').append("<div id="myDropZone" name="myDropZone" class='dropzone sales_proof_pic' data-proof-user-id='0'><div class='dz-message dropzone_placeholder color_khaki2' data-dz-message><span>UPLOAD<br>SALES<br>PROOF</span></div></div><input type='hidden' name='proof_id[0]' class='proof_pic_id'>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to detach the automaticall dropzone that comes by default.

Try this out of your Javascript document ready function or your load document.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

And declare the dropzone like this.

```
 var $dropzone = new Dropzone('#dropzone', {
       *//all your settings here.*
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If using jQuery, Dropzone.autoDiscover = false needs to be call before document.ready